# Any Obvious Consequences to Automatically Using const and Passing by Reference in Formal Parameter Lists?

Tags: c++

Over the last year or so, I've gotten into development more heavily on my own.  I find myself using `const` and `&` in my formal parameter lists as much as possible.  I'm not sure how I got into this habit, but unless I'm trying to change a value I send in, i automatically just give it `const` and I've pretty much entirely stopped passing by value.  I'm not sure why.  Are there any glaring consequences for automatically doing this? I'm assuming there might be some issues with execution time, but not entirely sure.  I realize there are no hard rules in programming, but are there any suggestions for this?  Is it wrong to automatically use `const` and passing by reference if possible? Or should I default to passing by value?

Comment: Unless you have run into any issues, stick with your habit.

Comment: If you want to use the copy-and-swap idiom then that's a case to pass by non-const value. Otherwise as long as it's for your own purposes I see no problem (but you should do some searching as I'm sure there are questions regarding issues/etc. with `const&` parameters).

Comment: I do the same thing, const references for everything I can, but I consciously don't do it for fundamental types.

Comment: When you say "Everything" do you mean for an *int* too?

Comment: int is fundamental, so no.

Comment: @mark I'm not familiar with the term "fundamentals" in this context, does that refer to standard C++ data types?

Comment: @joe_04_04 my question was for you too. Do you use const T& for int, double, pointers, smart pointers?

Comment: @jimifiki yes, I use it for everything, including int.  Is this something I should be avoiding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For built-in types (`int`, `bool`, `char`, `size_t`, `double`, etc.) and pointer types (`int*`, `char*`, etc.):

- **Pass by value.** There is no performance benefit to passing these by const reference, it just adds extra work for the compiler to optimize. Some people like to add `const` to pass-by-value 
  like `void f(const int x)`. This prevents accidentally modifying the value inside the function, at the cost of cluttering up the interface.
- Except, **pass by non-const reference** if the callee will modify it, and this is clear to the caller. This is basically only used to simulate a function returning multiple values.

For objects of class type (`class` and `struct`):

- **Pass by const reference** (`const std::string&, const std::vector<T>&`, `const MyClassOrStruct&`), if (1) the callee does not need to modify it, and (2) the callee will not hold on to the reference after the caller has destroyed it. This is probably the most common case for non-builtins.
- **Pass by non-const reference** if (1) the callee *does* need to modify it, (2) the callee will not hold on to the reference after the caller has destroyed it, and (3) it is clear to the caller that the passed object will be modified.
- **Pass by value** if need to make a copy of the object, and know that you are paying the price for a copy. For small struct-like types (such as `std::pair<int, int>` for example), it is okay to pass by value in general. For larger classes, you will need to look at your specific use-case.
- **Pass by move** if you will no longer need the original object and wish to transfer ownership to the function you are calling. This is often cheaper than a copy, but still has a cost. Generally pass lambdas and `std::function`s by move if possible.
- **Pass a `std::shared_ptr<T>` by value** if you would like to pass by reference, except the callee *does* need to hold on to the reference after the caller has destroyed it.
- **Pass a `std::unique_ptr<T>` by move** if you would like to pass by move, except that the move constructor is expensive, or you need the object to stay in place for some reason.

Comment: As far as I know there is not consensus about the best guideline for shared_ptrs and smart pointers in general. Do you mind to expand on the subject? How large is a smart pointer? (I prefer to pass shared_ptr by value but I don't have strong arguments to support this habit).

Comment: @jimifiki Passing a `shared_ptr` by value increases the refcount while passing by const reference does not; the semantics are different. You would pass a `shared_ptr` by value specifically when you want to extend the lifetime of the object by increasing the refcount. However, this is more expensive than passing by const reference since an atomic CPU instruction is needed, which I think is on the order of 100 cycles.

Comment: Thanks @Arcinde. I need some time to think about the implications of your comment. My first impression is that in many use cases the const reference is more appropriated: for instance when I call a plain function and I keep the pointed object in life while the function runs. I'll keep pondering.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky to say, because link-time optimizers have become crazy smart over the years, but on paper, you are paying a bit of a cost.

That's because, when you get down to it, references are essentially pointers in disguise.

Case in point:
https://godbolt.org/g/RZuYFj

Notice how the code with the `const&` has an extra instruction? That's caused by the extra dereferenciation, which is "somewhat" costly, but not as bad as it looks, because a cache hit is almost guaranteed in that case.

However, as I mentionned, compile-time optimizers are crazy good, and link-time optimizers are getting there. So I'd use the following rule of thumb:

1. For inline code, it almost certainly will never make a difference.
2. For linked code, you should assume you are paying a small cost if the type in question fits inside a single register.

Answer (score 1):

In leaf functions, passing by reference isn't likely to cause problems.

However, in non-leaf functions, passing by const reference can cause all kinds of grief, because you have to ensure that the reference stays live for the entire function call.  For parameters which are semantically pass by value, and the reference is introduced for efficiency (saving a copy), it's likely that the caller is not thinking about lifetime.

Consider the following code, which contains a bug:

```
std::vector<X> v = some_func();
assert(v.size() > 0);
v.push_back(v.front());
```

`std::vector<T>::push_back(const T&)` saves a copy by accepting its parameter by reference.  It also results in a constraint violation on perfectly reasonable-looking code like the above.  To wit, if `push_back` causes growth of the vector, it invalidates all existing iterators and pointers and references to elements.  The parameter is invalidated, breaking the requirement that arguments to library functions must be valid for the entire duration of the call.  The new location will be copy-constructed from an item that's either moved-from or even freed.  Inlining is no protection.

If `push_back` had accepted its argument by value, there would be no problem.

Comment: Another source of grief is aliasing. Consider: `int g; void x(const int& a) { if (a == 1) beep(); if (a == 1) g = 2; if (a == 1) beep(); }` The compiler cannot optimize this to `void x(const int& a) { if (a == 1) { beep(); g = 2; beep(); } }` because of the possibility that somebody called it as `g = 1; x(g)`!